# What signs indicate good water quality for tropical fish?

Tags: aquarium, freshwater, water-parameters

What are the signs of good water quality?

I want to add fish to my freshwater aquarium, and I want to make sure they have the least chance of dying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Check your water parameters, it should have 0 ammonia, 0 nitrite. Some nitrate presence is not lethal as long as it's within the limit.
- Match the pH and temperature depending on the species you plan to put it.
- Water should not be cloudy.
- There should not be any bio-film forming on top of the aquarium. In case it forms, increase surface agitation.
- Make sure your tank has enough filtration to support the bio-load.
- Tank decoration should match the requirement of the species. Some prefer less open area and more hiding place, some prefer the opposite. Some prefer plants, some prefer rock, some prefer a piece of wood.

Answer (score 4):

Some signs of good water quality:

- The normal pH levels of 6.5-7.5;
- The normal temperature of around 25 degrees Celsius;
- no ammonia, nitrite or nitrates present;
- algae present in small, controlled quantities.

Comment: I think the first two points are totally species dependent. Some species prefer higher pH, some lower. Some prefers low temperature, some higher.

Comment: Point me out a fish that prefers <6 or >8 pH.

Comment: Most african cichlids prefers pH >8... fishes from amazon basin prefers pH <6. But thats not the point, 6-8 is a big range, having a pH anywhere in between does not mean your fishes are happy.