# Why are my turtle’s eyes closed all the time?

Tags: turtles

[image]
I’ve noticed lately that my red eared slider is keeping her eyes closed most of the time and opening them only for maximum a minute and then closing them again. She lives in a big tank with a filter, light bulb, and a heater. The light bulb isn’t the issue because I bought her from a place that had this same tank with a bulb just like this one and all the other turtles seemed fine. I take her outside in the sun for uv light. I noticed today that when I took her outside, she opened her eyes and then when i took her back inside, she closed them. So what can be the cause of this unusual behavior?

Comment: Have you tested the water?

Comment: See Related [What signs indicate good water quality for tropical fish?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1411) it has some basic info about water